# What practical impact (if any) does the `fill_value` of a masked array have?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

When displaying a `MaskedArray`, I'm told the data, the mask, and the fill value.  Of course, data and mask are very important.  But what is the practical significance of the fill value?  I can even [change it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.set_fill_value.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.set_fill_value), but why would I want to do that — isn't the fill value just an implementation detail with no practical impact?

In other words: does the `fill_value` have any impact on any code not directly addressing `fill_value`?

Comment: Heh, good question (but maybe not a good stackoverflow question).  I'm flip-flopping between upvoting and voting to close. :)

Comment: It's not an implementation detail, it's a parameter for each array.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I rephrased the wording to avoid the impression of the question as subjective.  I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Well for one thing it specifies the default argument to `masked_array.filled()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `Masked_Array` class code, I see:

- methods for setting and getting `fill_value`
- `filled()` method, which returns a copy with the masked values replaced by the `fill_value`.  This is the 'direct' use of it.
- methods that call `filled` as part of their calculation.

`masked.all()` fills with `True` and then does the ordinary array `all`.

`masked.any()` fills with `False`.

`masked.nonzero()` does:

```
return narray(self.filled(0), copy=False).nonzero()
```

`trace` and `sum` also fill with 0, but `prod` fills with `1`.

`argsort` (and other methods like `argmin`) uses:

```
 d = self.filled(fill_value).view(ndarray)
```

Those methods take a `fill_value` parameter, or use the `self.fill_value`.  For methods like this the user potentially has strong preferences as to how the masked values are used in sorting or taking the minimum/maximum.

So `fill_value` is essential to efficient array calculation.  Some methods require a special value, others can use whatever the user wants.